# Confusion in the spectrum of FSK modulated signal by using matlab fskmod module

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, frequency, modulation

I want to do a comparison of power spectral density of BFSK, 4FSK and 8FSK by using matlab `baseband` module `"fskmod"`.Following is the code:

```
M = 2;
freqsep = 32;
nsamp = 4;
Fs = 64;
x = randint(1000,1,M); % Random signal
y = fskmod(x,M,freqsep,nsamp,Fs); % Modulate.
ly = length(y);
% Create an FFT plot.
freq = [-Fs/2 : Fs/ly : Fs/2 - Fs/ly];
Syy = 10*log10(fftshift(abs(fft(y))));
plot(freq,Syy)
```

With this configuration, I get a very good spectrum but when I change nsamp to 8 or any other value,multiple lobes start to appear between two frequencies. The confusion is in the understanding of the relation of nsamp and frequency separation. Could any one solve this confusion???

Comment: i meet the confusion too ,have you got any idear about it?

Comment: Have a look at a typical FSK spectrum [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/fskmod.html). Don't expect only two peaks at the two pulse frequencies, because the signal is not a sum of two perfect sinusoids. If your spectrum looks like the one in the link then it's OK, if not, then we have to look for the problem. BTW, I don't know the function `randint` (replaced by `randi`), but check if the maximum value of `x` is `M-1` (and not `M`!).